# Why is fork() before setsid() necessary, i.e. make child process not a group leader?

Tags: unix, daemon

When we are creating a daemon, we all know that the reason we fork() BEFORE setsid() is to make child process not a process group leader because we need to call setsid().

My question is, why is parent process maybe a process group leader? If fork() will make child process not process group leader, then why parent process is a group leader? Because parent process is forked by grand process right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell does it.

Interactive shells will make each executed program its own process group leader to enable job control (foregrounding and backgrounding of commands).

Here's an excerpt from the GNU documentation on [Implementing a Job Control Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Launching-Jobs.html):

> As each process is forked, it should put itself in the new process group by calling setpgid [...]

```
if (shell_is_interactive)
  {
    /* Put the process into the process group and give the process group
     the terminal, if appropriate.
     This has to be done both by the shell and in the individual
     child processes because of potential race conditions.  */
  pid = getpid ();
  if (pgid == 0) pgid = pid;
  setpgid (pid, pgid);
  if (foreground)
    tcsetpgrp (shell_terminal, pgid);
```